# Does corona discharge charged insulator?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage

Does corona discharge charged insulator? I draw a diagram to make it simpler to understand.

Electrons form negative side is accelerated due to electric field and accumulate on insulator surface. Gas on the positive side was ionize giving off electrons and flow to positive terminal.
[image]

Am I understanding this correctly, When I place plastic sheet between HV terminals and when I remove plastic sheet I got an electric shock, so I think corona discharge might charge plastic sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct. Indeed there is surface charge deposited on the surface of the insulator. This configuration is called a [Dielectric barrier discharge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_barrier_discharge). Its concept of work is explained in this [document](http://www.coronalab.net/wxzl/plasma-16.pdf). In section 2 it is clearly stated that the charge deposited on the surface of the dielectric play an important role in sustaining the discharge.

The more common configurations of DBD are concentric cylinders or parallel plates configurations. Still, sharp pin electrodes are common, they are not as common as the others because other configurations have certain functionality

When you switch off the discharge and touch the insulator by your hand you get shocked by the deposited surface charge on insulator's surface

Answer (score 1):

. . .  Well, anyway, you can get a shock through the insulator when it is under tension from a power supply or  source and the tension exceeds the breakdown threshold of  the insulator.   The conductor inside the insulator shorts through it and can shock you.

The other case, with no breakdown, depends on whether or not the dielectric in the insulator exhibits hysteresis.  The (insulator's) hysteresis is zero if the charge dipole built up within it at maximum applied tension returns to zero linearly as the applied tension returns to zero.  However, if the  built up charge dipole does not return to zero after the applied tension is removed, then the insulator is exhibiting hysteresis and the charge  remaining after the applied  tension is removed  may be available for discharge to an external conductor, such as your finger.  In this case you can get a delayed shock.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if a charged, insulated wire with Direct Current applied tension exhibits coronal dischage over a period of time, the insulator must be conducting and shorting to the outside.

Alternatiing applied tension is  much messier to analyze, but involves the dielecctric constants and the total capacitances of both the insulator and of the surrounding air.